# Como personalizar um link em CSS, exibindo a mensagem "visitado"?

Tags: html, css

Eu tentei colocar, no estilo, o status "visitado" ao lado do link após ele ser clicado, mas não consegui :/

Minha ideia era:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="google.com">Google <span>(visitado)</span></a></li>

</ul>
```

E no style:

```
<style>

    a > span { 
        display: none;
     }
    a:visited > span{ 
        display: inline-block;
     }

</style>
```

Porém, esse jeito não funciona. Como eu posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode alterar a propriedade `display:` com a pseudo-classe `:visited` por questões de **privacidade** do usuário e **não existe solução** alternativa para isso.

Apenas as seguintes propriedades são permitidas no `:visited`:

`color:`, `background-color:`, `border-color:`, `border-bottom-color:`, `border-left-color:`, `border-right-color:`, `border-top-color:`, `column-rule-color:`, `outline-color:`, `text-decoration-color:` e `text-emphasis-color:`.

Em SVG existem mais duas que são permitidas, `fill:` e `stroke:`.

Embora essas propriedades com o `:visited` possam alterar a aparência das cores para o usuário, a função `window.getComputedStyle()` **não** irá obter os valores alterados por `:visited` e sempre retornará o valor da cor **não visitada**.

Note que `:visited` só pode ser aplicado aos elementos `<a>` e `<area>`, o elemento `<link>` não suporta `:visited`.

Os motivos para os navegadores funcionarem assim é pela questão de privacidade do usuário, pois se fosse possível estilizar qualquer link poderia através do [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) ou [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) detectar qualquer link o usuário visitou e rastreá-lo, e o link nem precisaria existir na página atual, poderia ser adicionado dinamicamente, testando um range gigante de links, e ninguém quer ser rastreado sem consentimento.

Essa questão de privacidade começou a ser implementada em 2010 em todos navegadores, o que impactou muitos desenvolvedores, não só para rastreamento, mas para simples estilização e identificação do usuário final.

Para mais detalhes e aprender o básico e avançado de CSS recomendo sempre pesquisar primeiro na documentação da MDN, segue os links relacionados:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

Comment: **Nota:** eu não vou entrar no mérito técnico, mas algo que gostaria muito `:visited` funcionasse com qualquer propriedade desde que o link fosse do mesmo domínio da página atual, mesmo que o getComputedStyle() ou Element.matches() continuassem a "mentir" sobre os valores.